# How to use nameFilters with QDirIterator?

Tags: python, iterator, pyside, qdir

In PySide, when I use `QDirIterator`, how I can filter on files by name?

In the documentation, it talks about the parameter `nameFilters`:

- https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QDirIterator.html

But when I try it, it doesn't filter the files by extension:

```
from PySide import QtCore

it = QtCore.QDirIterator('.', nameFilters=['*.py'])
while it.hasNext():
    print it.next()

>> ./.
>> ./..
>> my_script.py
>> another_file.txt
```

With this code, I expected to get only the files with the extension `.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nameFilters` parameter is not a keyword argument.

Unfortunately, PySide never raises an error if you pass keyword arguments that don't exist, which is a very poor design. APIs should never fail silently when given invalid inputs.

Anyway, your code will work correctly if you use a positional argument:

```
it = QtCore.QDirIterator('.', ['*.py'])
```